# Geodesic incompleteness of static spherically symmetric solution

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, geodesics

Static spherically symmetric solution of Einstein equations is given by the metric
$$
ds^2=f(r)dt^2-\frac{dr^2}{f(r)}-r^2d\Omega^2,
$$
where $f(r)=1-(kr)^2$, $d\Omega^2$ is the metric of unit sphere.

I struggle with the notion of geodesic incompleteness. It is said that the space-time with metric given above is geodesic incomplete, but I can't understand how to show it.

Comment: Radial segments are geodesics for symmetry reasons. $r$ varies in a finite interval $(0, 1/k)$ by construction, the length parameter along such a geodesic is something like $s(r)=C+ k^{-1} \arcsin(kr)$. Thus it varies in a finite interval when moving along all the geodesic in its maximal extension. Hence the geodesic is incomplete.

Comment: Isn't this de Sitter spacetime, which is geodesically complete?

Comment: @ValterMoretti Thank you for the answer. Am I right that since $s(r)$ is finite it means that we can't move along this geodesic forever, which in turn means that it's incomplete? Also, is there a way to make this space complete?

Answer (score 0):

Geodesic incompleteness is defined by the existence of a geodesic that, under the evolution of time from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, terminates at some finite affine parameter. Hence, it is enough to construct a geodesic (by computing the Christoffel symbols and solving the geodesic equation with respect to the given metric) to obtain $s(t)$, inverting it into $t(s)$, and show that $t\to\infty$ or $t\to -\infty$ for some finite $s$.